# Kubernetes: Node vs Hosts vs Cluster terminology

Tags: kubernetes

http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/

"This guide will only get ONE node working. Multiple nodes requires a functional networking configuration done outside of kubernetes."

So, is a node made up of many hosts?
I thought cluster is made up of many hosts. Is the cluster made up of many nodes instead?

Each node had a master and minions so a cluster has more than one master?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- **Host**: some machine (physical or virtual)
- **Master**: a host running Kubernetes API server and other master systems
- **Node**: a host running `kubelet` + `kube-proxy` that pods can be scheduled onto
- **Cluster**: a collection of one or masters + one or more nodes

Comment: oh thats why the example is saying one node because its one node + one master. I was confused because in the example they were using two hosts but yet it says one node